# Blank Screen After Splash Screen

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I am new to windows phone development. In windows phone a blank screen is coming after a splash screen. I am using phonegap to build the app with windows. I tried it with different small applications but it is not working. what could be the reason I have googled it for an hour.

Comment: why are you using phonegap? i mean Windows phone SDK can build with javascript/html/css only

Comment: I have already developed for android and iOS. I want to use same for windows. How can I use same for windows.

Comment: i've never used phone gap for windows phone, but try to remove the splash file or debug it to see if you are getting into the content render function

Comment: I did that but no effect. Can you provide me some link for the whole flow of Windows Application Development lifecycle. So I can follow that.

Comment: This may help you (solutions to this problem on iOS and Android) get started: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20407634/158651

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was giving the wrong reference to the cordova.js file. I change the reference to the root directory of the project. After that it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

About flow: take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

About blinking: can you provide some code? It is not a common behavior for wp app.

Comment: Can you please tell the solution in brief. It would be helpful for many.